# jsblocks update view upon data update

Tags: javascript, model-view-controller, jsblocks

there is an object in my application , lets call it `myObject` , so `myObject` has some keys , and is being rendered in my html using [**jsblocks**](http://jsblocks.com/) library.

Due to lack of full documentation , I still can't figure out how to update my view upon updating this object from server side , for example :

```
function fetchArtists()
{
     // load data
        $.post( "../db/fetch/", { table: "artists"})
          .done(function( data ) {
            artists=JSON.parse(data);            
            //console.log( JSON.parse(data)  );
          });
}
```

this is a function that fetches object data from server and stores it in object artists.

and this is where i upgrade my view :

```
blocks.query(artists,$(".artist-list,.artist-data"));
```

I want to be able to use `blocks.observable(artists);` to upgrade view upon calling a new fetch , but it is not working , anyone knows the correct way to do this ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are on the right path when saying you should update the data with `blocks.observable`. The way you should do it should be something similar to the code below:

```
var Model = {
  artists: blocks.observable([])
};

function fetchArtists()
{
    // load data
    $.post( "../db/fetch/", { table: "artists"})
       .done(function( data ) {
           Model.artists.reset(JSON.parse(data));
       });
}

blocks.query(Model);
```